# Unable to access application container from iPad running on iOS 10 beta

Tags: ios10, xcode8-beta4, appcontainer

I am not able to download app container using xcode for my application on iOS 10 beta 4. I am using later xcode (beta 4). When I connect my device and go to `Device` in xcode, I am able to see my app listed but when I click on download container I get below error:

[image]

Is there anything to do with my app setting or device setting. How can I get my app data for iOS10 beta 4.

Comment: same problem here.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I updated to macOS but I'm having the same problem

Comment: I come to know (from unofficial sources of course) that apps created with older xcode have this problem. Create build from xcode8 and try it, it should work.

Comment: Built my app with Xcode8 - I am having this issue as well:
XCode Version 8.0 (8A218a)
iOS 10.0.2
OSX 10.11.6+

Answer (score 14):

Further testing indicates this could be related to the fact that **only containers from debug builds are downloadable**. Versions built as Release/Distribution builds don't seem to allow the application container to download.

[Here is the apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60674)

Comment: I get the same results. Still puzzled by the absence of an official response on apple forum (even if I know this's almost the norm sadly...)

Comment: I built a Xamarin app in VS2015 as debug, and still get the same error when trying to download the app container using xcode devices

Comment: I have updated my observations: I can do this on an iPhone6, but not an iPos with both on the same iOS version, and same app build. The difference seems to be some older provisioning profiles for previous versions on the app that are present on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Quit Xcode.
2. Reboot the iPad.
3. Reopen Xcode and connect.

Answer found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144387/an-error-occured-while-attempting-to-download-the-container-from-application-xco) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139144/an-error-occured-while-attempting-to-download-the-container-from-application-xco) post.

Comment: surprisingly, this fixed it for me (was already on debug build)