# An error occured while attempting to download the container from application Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode7

While running my app on iPhone, I needed to view the database contents. So I selected Devices in Xcode and chose my device. Thereafter, I selected my app and clicked on the Settings button which shows 3 options: Show container, Download container and Remove container. On clicking the Download container option, I was asked where I want to store the container. After selecting the location, I am getting the following error: `An error occured while attempting to download the container from application "MyApp".....`

On selecting Show container option, a list opens up but there is no file inside it.

The same problem occurs with other apps too that I run using Xcode.

Any ideas as to why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Please don't cross post. http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/250499/revisions

Comment: got it.. wasn't sure where to post it, so did it in both places

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An error occured while attempting to download the container from application Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144387/an-error-occured-while-attempting-to-download-the-container-from-application-xco)

Answer (score 4):

Restarting the device in question worked for me. Hope it helps!