# An error occured while attempting to download the container from application Xcode

Tags: xcode

While running my app on iPhone, I needed to view the database contents. So I selected Devices in Xcode and chose my device. Thereafter, i selected my app and clicked on the Settings button which shows 3 options: Show container, Download container and Remove container. On clicking the Download container option, I was asked where I want to store the container. After selecting the location, I am getting the following error: An error occured while attempting to download the container from application "MyApp".....

On selecting Show container option, a list opens up but there is no file inside it.

The same problem occurs with other apps too that I run using Xcode.

Any ideas as to why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I am having the same issue. The first time I had it was yesterday and I couldn't do anything to fix it. I tried again today and it worked for about 3 hours and I am getting the same error. Restarting Xcode, macbook nothing seems to be solving this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just rebooted my iPhone. That seems to fix it! Really weird, but works.

I have been having the issue every now and then especially after the phone has been connected to Mac and Xcode for about an hour.

Sometimes, just rebooting the phone isn't good enough, you'll also have to quit Xcode and start again after rebooting the phone!

Comment: But isn't there a reason for this?

Comment: This isn't working in my case, for an Enterprise saved app.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem yesterday, and the solution was a mismatched version of iOS 10 and Xcode 7.  After I did the App Store upgrade to Xcode 8, I was able to download successfully.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the issue was due to the fact that the version installed was a release version.
After installing the "Debug" version, the download worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue while downloading the container. I connected my iphone and mac with cable.
I tried rebooting the phone, xcode quit and relaunch and event restarted the mac. But still I was facing the same issue.

Resolution -

1. Disconnect the iphone cable from mac.
2. Now **connect the iphone to xcode via network**. You must be using same wifi connection on iphone and mac system.
3. Then try to download the container.
4. I worked for me.

How to connect iphone to xcode via network.

1. Connect to the same wifi on both mac and iphone.
2. From xcode -> Windows -> Devices and Simulator -> Select your iphone.
3. There would be a checkbox - Connect via network. Tick on it.
4. It will ask you to enter you iphone password. Once you enter, you will get connected.